# How To Obtain Username/chatname of a telegram group With Python-Telegram-Bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm Creating A Telegram Bot Using Python-Telegram-Bot
I need to know the group username or chatname so that I can code such a way to my bot only work in my group.
How do I get a group username or chatname using python?
I just do like this
let's say my Telegram group name 'A'

```
if chatname=='A':
     #do something
```

let's say my Telegram group username  @abc

```
if usename=='abc':
       #do something
```

Is there any way to get a group username or chatname in python telebot?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
update.message.chat.title
```

This will return Title, for supergroups, channels and group chats